# Executing script through Cron getting error TERM environment variable not set

Tags: linux, bash, cron

when I tried to schedule cronjob for a script I got the following message

---

```
 Server ~]# crontab -e
```

> /bin/sh: /usr/bin/vi: No such file or directory
>
> crontab: "/usr/bin/vi" exited with status 127

---

so I set it using these commands

```
Server ~]# ls -ltr /bin/vi

-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 770248 Jun 23  2012 /bin/vi*

[Server_name ~]# ln -s /bin/vi /usr/bin/vi
```

And I scheduled cronjob to run the shellscript and I am receiving error in vi /var/spool/mail/root as

> TERM environment variable not set

---

I checked the if term is set using the command

```
set | grep TERM
```

and i am getting output

> TERM=vt100

I went through existing questions on this topic but couldn't come with a solution. What further changes shall I need to do or am I missing something here?

Comment: what is your job trying to do? if it's invoking something that requires a terminal, it ain't going to work. cron jobs have no terminal. they run in the background.

Comment: I am trying to run a trim script for my SSD's.http://www.howtogeek.com/176978/ubuntu-doesnt-trim-ssds-by-default-why-not-and-how-to-enable-it-yourself/

Comment: Why do you feel a need to call `vi` in your _trim script_?